# Recursively adding words to a LinkedHashMap character by character

Tags: java, recursion

I'm trying to write a class into which I can enter words, and a tree of characters will be created from the entered word. The tree can then be checked whether a certain word exists in it. My issue is that I can only get it to save one character from any word - if a word has more than one character, only the first one is saved (I'm pretty sure the contains method is right). This is my code, something is evidently wrong with it however I can't tell what:

```
public class Dictionary {

  private Map<Character, DictionaryTree> children = new LinkedHashMap<>();
  private boolean endOfWord;

  DictionaryTree() {
    endOfWord = false;
  }

  void insert(String word) {
    if (!contains(word)) {
      DictionaryTree newDictionaryTree = new DictionaryTree();
      if (word.length() > 1) {
        newDictionaryTree.insert(word.substring(1, word.length()));
      } else if (word.length() == 1) {
        newDictionaryTree.endOfWord = true;
      }
      children.put(word.charAt(0), newDictionaryTree);
    }
  }

  boolean contains(String word) {
    if (word.length() > 0) {
      // Check if first letter is a child node
      if (children.containsKey(word.charAt(0))) {
        if (word.length() > 1) {
          DictionaryTree extractedDictionaryTree = children.get(word.charAt(0));
          extractedDictionaryTree.contains(word.substring(1, word.length()));
        }
        // If only one character left, check if end of word
        else if (children.get(word.charAt(0)).endOfWord == true) {
          return true;
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      }
      return false;
    }

    return false;
  }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why do you say that something is wrong? Any unexpected behavior you want to share? :)

Comment: @Alfabravo It only works for 1 character words - anything beyond 1 character simply doesn't save properly - contains doesn't return true.

Comment: Consider posting [mcve] with test data

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirement you want to search a word, if it exists or not.
You will achieve it with `LinkedHashmap` but you try with the `Trie` data structure. Which provides the efficient way to insert as well as search the String or any data in an efficient way.

Source code is referenced from [GeeksForGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/trie-insert-and-search/)

```
                   root
                /   \    \
                t   a     b
                |   |     |
                h   n     y
                |   |  \  |
                e   s  y  e
             /  |   |
             i  r   w
             |  |   |
             r  e   e
                    |
                    r
```

**Implementation:**

```
// Java implementation of search and insert operations
// on Trie
public class Trie {

    // Alphabet size (# of symbols)
    static final int ALPHABET_SIZE = 26;

    // trie node
    static class TrieNode
    {
        TrieNode[] children = new TrieNode[ALPHABET_SIZE];

        // isEndOfWord is true if the node represents
        // end of a word
        boolean isEndOfWord;

        TrieNode(){
            isEndOfWord = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < ALPHABET_SIZE; i++)
                children[i] = null;
        }
    };

    static TrieNode root; 

    // If not present, inserts key into trie
    // If the key is prefix of trie node, 
    // just marks leaf node
    static void insert(String key)
    {
        int level;
        int length = key.length();
        int index;

        TrieNode pCrawl = root;

        for (level = 0; level < length; level++)
        {
            index = key.charAt(level) - 'a';
            if (pCrawl.children[index] == null)
                pCrawl.children[index] = new TrieNode();

            pCrawl = pCrawl.children[index];
        }

        // mark last node as leaf
        pCrawl.isEndOfWord = true;
    }

    // Returns true if key presents in trie, else false
    static boolean search(String key)
    {
        int level;
        int length = key.length();
        int index;
        TrieNode pCrawl = root;

        for (level = 0; level < length; level++)
        {
            index = key.charAt(level) - 'a';

            if (pCrawl.children[index] == null)
                return false;

            pCrawl = pCrawl.children[index];
        }

        return (pCrawl != null && pCrawl.isEndOfWord);
    }

    // Driver
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        // Input keys (use only 'a' through 'z' and lower case)
        String keys[] = {"the", "a", "there", "answer", "any",
                         "by", "bye", "their"};

        String output[] = {"Not present in trie", "Present in trie"};


        root = new TrieNode();

        // Construct trie
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < keys.length ; i++)
            insert(keys[i]);

        // Search for different keys
        if(search("the") == true)
            System.out.println("the --- " + output[1]);
        else System.out.println("the --- " + output[0]);

        if(search("these") == true)
            System.out.println("these --- " + output[1]);
        else System.out.println("these --- " + output[0]);

        if(search("their") == true)
            System.out.println("their --- " + output[1]);
        else System.out.println("their --- " + output[0]);

        if(search("thaw") == true)
            System.out.println("thaw --- " + output[1]);
        else System.out.println("thaw --- " + output[0]);

    }
}
```

Hope it helps!!!

Comment: Is [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/trie-insert-and-search/) the source for your answer ?